# Elasticsearch shard crashing

Tags: elasticsearch

I am having an issue with one of my elasticsearch shards crashing and restarting the node does not fix the issue.  I have a machine dedicated to elasticsearch that has 16GB of RAM with a 8GB heap size.  I am running only one node with 2 shards and no replicas.  The cluster stats list that we have 741,189 documents and 1.2GB of data, we had 2.5GB before the shard crashed.

I have a very insert, update, and retrieval heavy application and about the time we reach 2.5GB of data and 1,000,000 documents one of the shards crashes and can not be restarted.  The only way that I have found to fix the issue I am having to to delete all of the data and reindex the node.  The shard crash about every 3 to 4 days now and the rate in which data is being added to the system is expected to increase over time.  I am happy to provide any other information that may be helpful in fixing this issue.

Comment: Does it crash with an OutOfMemory error? Could your filter and field data caches be getting too large?

Comment: Also, what do you mean by the shard crashes? each node is a JVM right not each shard? You only have one JVM/node running?

Comment: I am not getting an out of memory error the machine that I am running elasticsearch on has 16GB of RAm with a 8GB heap size and a 256GB SSD hard drive but I only have 2.5GB of data.  It is a single node running two shards (in anticipation of a second node being added later so I will not have to re-index). I think that the some of the segments in the shard are getting corrupt, when I restart the node I get a java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException error.  After some more research I ran fixIndex() that removed the corrupt segments(luckily my data was recoverable).

Comment: Stefanie, if the issue is solved, you may consider adding your own answer and detailing a bit the fixIndex() stuff (how to apply, some other references...)